# Animating UIView with UIViewContentModeCenter causes break in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm attempting to animate a UIView that has all of its content drawn in the drawRect method. If I try to animate the view with the default settings, the content gets stretched out in a really unappealing manner.

My solution was to change the content mode of the view to UIViewContentModeCenter. As the content in the view is centered anyways, this made the animation look great. However, the background of my view pulls away from the edges of the view leaving blank space at the sides.

Is there some way for me to extend my background before the cell animates to its larger size, so that I don't run into this problem? My background is a gradient, if that makes things trickier.